# How to use sed/grep to extract text between two diffrent strings (+ the 2 strings) that contain "/and *"

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am trying to extract the text between two strings that contain the symbols / and *. I believe this is the reason the regex commands break. So my starting string is "/25043*" and my ending string is "*25043/". I have the extract the text between these two strings (including these 2 strings) from a text file.

I've tried this using : `grep -o -P '(?<="/25043*").*(?="*25043/")' code.txt`

which gives me an error : `"grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length"`

My input file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 256
/25043/definiramo konstanto MAX

int main(){
    /25043*Vstopna tocka programa
    Ne uporabljamo parameterov pri main, kjer jih ne potrebujemo

    *25043/
    printf("");/25043/izpis vrednosti konstante MAX

    return 0;
}
/25043/Koncamo z izvajanjem programa
```

My wanted output:

```
/25043*Vstopna tocka programa
        Ne uporabljamo parameterov pri main, kjer jih ne potrebujemo
    
*25043/
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping those two characters? Writing `\/` and `\*`.

Comment: Yes I've done that aswell... tried for both / and * and together aswell. Also tried making a variable for each string and executing the grep with vartiables, that also didn't help.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I fixed the problem with the special symbols. Now the problem is that it only works for single line inputs.

Comment: Your desired output does not match your question. You wrote "text **between** two strings". What you have shown is with the two strings.

Comment: Yeah in desc I wrote what exactly I want though... "I have the extract the text between these two strings (including these 2 strings) from a text file."

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep -Po`, you could use `grep -oPz '(?s)/25043\*.*?\*25043/' file`, but this solution has some drawbacks, namely, the value extracted has no line contents before `/25043*` and there is no trailing newline at the end.

The best approach here is to use `awk`:

```sh
awk '/\/25043\*/,/\*25043\//' file
```

Output:

```
    /25043*Vstopna tocka programa
    Ne uporabljamo parameterov pri main, kjer jih ne potrebujemo

    *25043/
```

Note that `/` and `*` have to be escaped here (`/` is a regex delimiter char, and the `*` is a special regex metacharacter).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

based on the OP edit try using `-z` as it treats as large string
so :

```
grep -zoP '/25043\*(.|\s)*\*25043/' code.txt
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

have you tried to do it without grouping? like so :

example assumption of `code.txt`:

```
asdf asdfasd /25403* asdf *25043/ asdfa asdfa
```

command:

```
grep -o '/25403\* .* \*25043/' code.txt
```

result is :

```
/25403* asdf *25043/
```

Comment: The command works but the I found out that the reason it doesn't work for me is because my code.txt file is a multiple line text. Do you maybe know how I could use it to work there aswell? So my string1 is on a different line as string2.

Comment: try to use `grep -zoP ` and regex `\s`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use awk, and are looking for a more portable solution, you could try this:

```
sed '/\/25043\*/,/\*25043\//!d;s/\(\*25043\/\).*$/\1/g' file
```